# Turn Null Counts To Show As 0 PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I am trying to get a count of generated leads and noticed I have a rep that is missing two weeks of data. I'm assuming it's because that person was on vacation and has null values during those dates and the left join won't display the dates with null values.

I was wondering how to make the dates where people have null to display as 0 in the count column.

This is my current code:

```
select
  t.date, t.michelle_finwell_target, f.name, f.cat, f.c_date_applied::date,
  Count(f.*) "count"
from servicing_targets t
  left join finwell_leads f on t.date::date = f.c_date_applied::date
Where
  name = 'Michelle'
group by
  t.date, t.michelle_finwell_target, f.name, f.cat, f.c_date_applied::date
order by
  f.c_date_applied::date asc
```

And these are my results:

[image]

The date and c_date_applied columns jump from 2020-10-20 to 2020-11-03.

How do I alter the query to display a count of 0 for the workdays between 10/20 and 11/3?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. You have many columns in the `group by` clause, but just one row per day in the resultset, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: Use `generate_series(timestamp,timestamp,interval)` to generate column of dates. Join them with this user. Then join it with your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where name = 'Michelle'` transforms your `left join` to `inner join`. Compare:

```
with t1(x) as (values(1),(2)), t2(x,y) as (values(1,11))
select *
from t1 left join t2 on (t1.x = t2.x);
┌───┬──────┬──────┐
│ x │  x   │  y   │
├───┼──────┼──────┤
│ 1 │    1 │   11 │
│ 2 │ ░░░░ │ ░░░░ │
└───┴──────┴──────┘

with t1(x) as (values(1),(2)), t2(x,y) as (values(1,11))
select *
from t1 left join t2 on (t1.x = t2.x)
where t2.y=11;
┌───┬───┬────┐
│ x │ x │ y  │
├───┼───┼────┤
│ 1 │ 1 │ 11 │
└───┴───┴────┘
```

If you want to preserve empty rows from the right-hand table in the `left join` then move related conditions to the `join` expression:

```
with t1(x) as (values(1),(2)), t2(x,y) as (values(1,11))
select *
from t1 left join t2 on (t1.x = t2.x and t2.y=11);
┌───┬──────┬──────┐
│ x │  x   │  y   │
├───┼──────┼──────┤
│ 1 │    1 │   11 │
│ 2 │ ░░░░ │ ░░░░ │
└───┴──────┴──────┘
```

With your query it should be:

```
select
  t.date, t.michelle_finwell_target, f.name, f.cat, f.c_date_applied::date,
  Count(f.*) "count"
from servicing_targets t
  left join finwell_leads f on t.date::date = f.c_date_applied::date and name = 'Michelle'
group by
  t.date, t.michelle_finwell_target, f.name, f.cat, f.c_date_applied::date
order by
  f.c_date_applied::date asc
```

Comment: awesome, thank you for the visual! that helped a lot!